# JavaScript - For loop button onclick - identify which button

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I'm creating 5 divisions in for loop, each division have one image and one button.
Button's action is to perform like/vote. But, the images and buttons being in for loop, i don't know which button is linked with which image id. So that i can put it into database that image have been voted.

```
<%
for(until resultSet has next){
    %>
        <img id="img" src="resultsetValue" />
        <button id="btn" >VOTE</button>
    <%
}
%>
```

In JavaScript file:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    //WHICH IMAGE NEEDS VOTE NOW
}
```

Now, if you see, i gave them id's too. An id must be unique to each element, but i gave id in for loop, which makes every image and every button have same id. How can i resolve this or is it ok?

i don't want to use jQuery, i have to learn it yet.

Comment: Typo `document`, not `documnet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure buttons don't have duplicated ids. Better to use classes in this case:

```
<% for(until resultSet has next) { %>
    <img id="img<%= index %>" src="resultsetValue" />
    <button class="btn" data-index="<%= index %>">VOTE</button>
<% } %>
```

Then you can do something like this using iteration index to refer currently clicked element:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        var index = this.getAttribute('data-index');
        var img = document.querySelector('#img' + index);
    };
}
```

this one will work

Comment: so, getElementById() is useless here? Will i have any closure issues of onclick in it?